# Getting org.apache.geode.cache.TransactionDataNotColocatedException: for Partitioned region while performing Transaction

Tags: gemfire, geode

Below is my Peer to Peer Geode Cluster Configuration

Locator ->

```
LocatorLauncher locatorLauncher = new LocatorLauncher.Builder()
            .setMemberName("locator1")
            .setPort(13489)
            .build();

    locatorLauncher.start();
    locatorLauncher.waitOnLocator();
```

Peer1 ->

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("locators", "localhost[13489]");
    properties.setProperty("mcast-address", "224.0.0.0");
    properties.setProperty("mcast-port", "0");
    properties.setProperty(NAME, "Member1");

    CacheFactory cacheFactory = new CacheFactory(properties);

    Cache cache = cacheFactory.create();
```

Peer 2 ->

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("locators", "localhost[13489]");
    properties.setProperty("mcast-address", "224.0.0.0");
    properties.setProperty("mcast-port", "0");
    properties.setProperty(NAME, "Member12");

    CacheFactory cacheFactory = new CacheFactory(properties);

    Cache cache = cacheFactory.create();
```

Then I have a partition region

```
RegionFactory<String, Person> regionFactory = this.cache.createRegionFactory(RegionShortcut.PARTITION);
    region = regionFactory.create("Person");
```

When I am trying to insert bulk insert in this region

```
Map<String, Person> transactionData = new HashMap();
    int id = Integer.parseInt(start);
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        Person person = createPerson("Agent" + (i + id), "");
        transactionData.put(person.getFirstName(), person);
    }

    CacheTransactionManager cacheTransactionManager = cache.getCacheTransactionManager();
    cacheTransactionManager.begin();
    region.putAll(transactionData);
    cacheTransactionManager.commit();

private Person createPerson(String firstname, String lastname) {
    Person person = new Person(firstname, lastname);
    IdentifierSequence.INSTANCE.setSequentialLongId(person);
    return person;
}
```

I am getting below exception

```
org.apache.geode.cache.TransactionDataNotColocatedException: Key Agent142 is not colocated with transaction, caused by org.apache.geode.internal.cache.PrimaryBucketException: Bucket 94 is not primary. Current primary holder is 192.168.40.214(cacheServer2:20928)<v1>:41001
at org.apache.geode.internal.cache.TXStateProxyImpl.getTransactionException(TXStateProxyImpl.java:224)
at org.apache.geode.internal.cache.TXStateProxyImpl.putEntry(TXStateProxyImpl.java:612)
at org.apache.geode.internal.cache.LocalRegion.basicPut(LocalRegion.java:5119)
at org.apache.geode.internal.cache.TXState$1.run(TXState.java:2046)
at org.apache.geode.internal.cache.event.NonDistributedEventTracker.syncBulkOp(NonDistributedEventTracker.java:114)
at org.apache.geode.internal.cache.LocalRegion.syncBulkOp(LocalRegion.java:6117)
at org.apache.geode.internal.cache.TXState.postPutAll(TXState.java:2033)
at org.apache.geode.internal.cache.TXStateProxyImpl.postPutAll(TXStateProxyImpl.java:840)
at org.apache.geode.internal.cache.LocalRegion.basicPutAll(LocalRegion.java:9552)
at org.apache.geode.internal.cache.LocalRegion.putAll(LocalRegion.java:9300)
at org.apache.geode.internal.cache.LocalRegion.putAll(LocalRegion.java:9312)
at com.trendcore.cache.peertopeer.CacheInteractor.executeTransactions(CacheInteractor.java:185)

...Caused by: org.apache.geode.internal.cache.PrimaryBucketException: Bucket 94 is not primary. Current primary holder is 192.168.40.214(cacheServer2:20928)<v1>:41001
at org.apache.geode.internal.cache.PartitionedRegion.getDataRegionForWrite(PartitionedRegion.java:9404)
at org.apache.geode.internal.cache.PartitionedRegion.getDataRegionForWrite(PartitionedRegion.java:254)
at org.apache.geode.internal.cache.TXState.txReadEntry(TXState.java:1533)
at org.apache.geode.internal.cache.TXState.txWriteEntry(TXState.java:1314)
at org.apache.geode.internal.cache.TXState.txPutEntry(TXState.java:1368)
at org.apache.geode.internal.cache.TXState.putEntry(TXState.java:1711)
at org.apache.geode.internal.cache.TXStateProxyImpl.putEntry(TXStateProxyImpl.java:607)
... 23 more
```

Question:-

Is there a better way to perform the bulk insert in the partition region inside a transaction along with rebalancing of data.

I modified my region attribute and tried to to do the bulk operation with below configuration

```
    PartitionAttributesFactory partitionAttributesFactory = new PartitionAttributesFactory();
    PartitionResolver resolver = new StandardPartitionResolver();
    partitionAttributesFactory.setPartitionResolver(resolver);
    PartitionAttributes partitionAttributes = partitionAttributesFactory.create();
    region = regionFactory.setPartitionAttributes(partitionAttributes).create("Person");
```

StandardPartitionResolver ->

```
     public class StandardPartitionResolver implements PartitionResolver<String, Person> {

        @Override
        public Object getRoutingObject(EntryOperation<String, Person> opDetails) {
            return "1";
        }

        @Override
        public String getName() {
            return getClass().getName();
        }
    }
```

With PartitionResolver, bulk insert executed in expected.
But when executed below code to check which partition holds which data

```
Region<String, Person> localData = PartitionRegionHelper.getLocalData(personRegion);
    return localData.values().stream();
```

All data goes to either partition 1 ( or partition 2). Apache Geode is not re-balancing partition after bulk execution is done.

Do I have to manually call rebalance operation ?

Answer (score 0):

Geode only supports transactions on data that is all within the same bucket. So in this case, your single bulk operation is going to multiple buckets, resulting in the TransactionDataNotColocatedException.

When you created your StandardPartitionResolver, that put *all* data in a single bucket. Buckets can't be split up, so all of your data will end up on one server.

Your best bet is to use separate transactions for the different buckets you are putting into. That will ensure that all data that is part of a single transaction is colocated.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. There is a way to do this for partition region by setting cache transaction manager distributed flag to true. I have posted the answer with sample code. Let me know if there a better way or if I have missed something.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say we have user region and this is without any StandardPartitionResolver Attribute

```
RegionFactory<Long, User> regionFactory = this.cache.createRegionFactory(RegionShortcut.PARTITION);
    userRegion = regionFactory.create(USER_REGION);
```

and still if we want to bulk insert data into partition region in a single transaction

```
Map<Long, User> transactionData = new HashMap();
    int id = Integer.parseInt(start);
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        User user = createUser("Agent" + (i + id), "");
        user.setId((long) (i+id));
        transactionData.put(user.getId(), user);
    }

    CacheTransactionManager cacheTransactionManager = cache.getCacheTransactionManager();
    cacheTransactionManager.setDistributed(true); //This is required
    cacheTransactionManager.begin();
    userRegion.putAll(transactionData);
    cacheTransactionManager.commit();
```

then we need to set "cacheTransactionManager.setDistributed(true);"

This will not give TransactionDataNotColocatedException.

Not sure though what is the performance and consequence but as per the Documentation Partition regions are great if number of writes are more than number of reads.

Comment: Any idea whether same can be done using spring boot properties?